# Android App with Location Services is detected as Virus

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I'm playing around with Android App Development and want to use the Geofencing API from Google.
As soon as I add the followeing to my build.gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'`

The App gets tagged by the Huawei Optimizer App (by Avast) as a Virus by the Name "FakeSys-Q".
Any Ideas how to fix this? 
It's not a problem I ever encountered with any PlayStore App on this Device (Huawei P30 Pro with Google Services).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect this may be related to the fact that your app is a debug build and thus not signed with a real key on the PlayStore. Perhaps you can manually tell the Optimizer that you app is not a threat.

Comment: Signing the app and building a release apk solved this Problem, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signing the app and build a release apk solved the Problem.